# Perforce does not allow Obliterate files

Tags: filesystems, config, perforce

When attempting to **obliterate** files I receive the following error:

> The filesystem '.p4-extensions' has only 4.9G free, but the server configuration requires at least 5G available.

'.p4-extensions' is not listed as one of the settings that can be altered in the configurables. I'd like to lower the threshold long enough to complete the **obliterate** command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it mentions .p4-extensions specifically but take a look at the filesys.P4ROOT.min configurable and the others similar to it here:
https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/configurables.alphabetical.html?Highlight=filesys.P4ROOT.min

Hopefully setting those to a lower value will allow you to issue the obliterate command.